# How to return object with byte array property by WEB API?

Tags: c#

I am writing a web API to return an object with a byte array property, something like this in the controller:

```
...
car.name=Cruze;
car.Image=[123,145,10,...] // image data as byte[]

return Ok(car);
```

On the UI, I can see the returned car object, but the `car.Image` property is converted to `Base64String`.

I am not sure why this happens. How can I make sure the `car.Image` is sent as `byte[]` to client?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All communication between your server and the client must be serialized. So your byte array will be serialized among everything else. The standard serialization used in this case is the `Base64String`.

Actually if you want to use your image on the website, then the `Base64String` has just made it easier for you. All you need is to add `data:image/jpeg;base64,` at the beginning of the string and use it wherever you usually use the image URL. Change `jpeg` to the type of your image. Examples:

HTML:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,..." />
```

JavaScript:

```
img.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64,...";
```

CSS:

```
URL("data:image/jpeg;base64,...")
```

You can also load it to a canvas if you like to edit the image using the HTML5 capabilities.

If you're using a client other than the browser, there is increasing number of libraries to convert between `Base64String` and images in any programming framework, so just look for one for your framework.

If you want to use the byte array for something else, you can easily decode the `Base64String` back to a byte array.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, Racil. The Base64String adds about 33% more bytes to the initial array, this increases the payload of the traffic. Since we have a lot of images to send by the API, it would be better if the API can just send the pure byte[] and we can do the conversion on client side. This will reduce the work load for the API server as well.

Comment: You're counting 33% without taking into consideration the compression. All traffic between your API and the client is compressed, so it is practically much less than 33% and could be even smaller. Test your API in the browser to see the actual compressed size. Here is [how you can check it in Chrome](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4607/is-there-an-easy-way-to-see-amount-of-compression-in-chrome).

Comment: Just to be clear, everything you send between the server and client is serialized. So if you don't like the default `Base64String` serialization of your byte array, then you can manually serialize it in any way you want. You will then realize that it will be hard for you to beat the efficiency of the `Base64String` serialization. You say it adds 33%, try to beat that. It is the standard binary serialization for a reason.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply and I'll take it. :)

Answer (score 6):

Web API communication happens over HTTP. HTTP does not know anything about `byte[]`. Because your `byte[]` is part of C# and HTTP does not know anything about C# either.

So it is correctly serialised as `Base64String` (this is the best thing to do, really) and your client needs to decode Base64 into byte array for further processing.